# Get index of elements in first Series within the second series

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series

I want to get the index of all values in the `smaller` series for the `larger` series. The answer is in the code snippet below stored in the `ans` variable.

```
import pandas as pd

smaller = pd.Series(["a","g","b","k"])
larger = pd.Series(["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m"])

# ans to be generated by some unknown combination of functions
ans = [0,6,1,10]
print(larger.iloc[ans,])
print(smaller)
assert(smaller.tolist() == larger.iloc[ans,].tolist())
```

Context: Series `larger` serves as an index for the columns in a numpy matrix, and series `smaller` serves as an index for the columns in a numpy vector. I need indexes for the matrix and vector to match.

Comment: It's a lot easier to do using list comprehension. But, I guess you already know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse your `larger` series, then index this with `smaller`:

```
larger_rev = pd.Series(larger.index, larger.values)
res = larger_rev[smaller].values

print(res)

array([ 0,  6,  1, 10], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Impressed by your answer, accepting this when the cool off period for accepting answers is over.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for i in list(smaller):
        if i in list(larger):
            print((list(larger).index(i)))
```

This will get you the desired output

Answer (score 1):

Using `Series` `get`

```
pd.Series(larger.index, larger.values).get(smaller)
Out[8]: 
a     0
g     6
b     1
k    10
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :)

```
    import pandas as pd
    larger = pd.Series(["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m"])
    smaller = pd.Series(["a","g","b","k"])

    res = pd.Series(larger.index, larger.values).reindex(smaller.values, copy=True)
    print(res)
```